# Order by an expression in Solr

Tags: solr

In SQL you can order by an expression like:

```
SELECT * FROM a
ORDER BY CASE WHEN a.Category = 20 THEN 1 ELSE 0 DESC
```

so records who have Category = 20 are on top.

Is this possible in Solr?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solr doesn't have an [if/then (at least not until 4.0)](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2136), but it does have a map function and the ability to use [function queries](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery) in your [sort](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters). You can probably use something like this in your sort to achieve what you're after:

```
 ?q=*&sort=map(category,20,20,case,0),score desc
```

(untested)

Here is a thread that talks about [using map for an if statement](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Sorting-function-with-condition-td2970036.html).

Comment: Thanks, just a bummer that we are running 1.4 and functions in sort are supported as of 3.1.

Answer (score 1):

I've accepted hross's answer, but it's also possible to do something like this in Solr 1.3 and up, using:

```
/select?q={!func}map(Category,20,20,1,0)&sort=score desc
```

The cool thing is that you can still sort on other fields, so:

```
&sort=score desc, name asc
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the dismax request handler, then you can use boost queries in a similar fashion. http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin#bq_.28Boost_Query.29 Note that this doesn't function exactly like the your SQL example, but you can achieve the same results with it.

Comment: The problem with boosting this way is that you cannot sort by other fields (at least to what I've found).