# Sort Solr Documents based on another array

Tags: solr, geospatial, distance

I have two solr schemas. One for `items` and one for `geolocation` of items. I want to sort my items by distance, with nearer items first. `Items` schema has `product_id,city_id,etc,etc` and `geolocation` schema has `city_id,name,lat_lon` fields. My requirement is to show the results which are less than `d` kilometers from user `cityId`. I can get all the cities ids which are in `d` kms range from `geolocation` schema using bbox filter and then sort by distance using `geodist()` function  and then pass this list of ids as a filter query to items schema. But i also want the items to be appear in the same order of cities id.

Like in MySql : select * from items where city_id in (58748,15741) ORDER BY Field(city_id,15741,58748)

Is there any solution to achieve this in solr?

Answer (score 0):

1. use one schema for both items and the geolocation of items. There is no need to have two schemas.you can have item and geolocation properties as different fields in one scheme.
2. take a look at [function queries](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#dist)  the 27 th item **dist** would calculate distance for you.
3. for ordering, it is enough to use **asc** and **desc** after the field look at [stack overflow answer in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6437512/order-by-an-expression-in-solr).