# solr sorting intended only for two document

Tags: solr, lucene

Please see my sample solr document below.

```
{
   "title": "Apple"
},
{
  "title": "Banana",
  "popularity": 2
},
{
  "title": "Mango",
  "popularity": 3
},
{
  "title": "Lemon",
  "popularity": 1
}
```

By default the query is "title":* so all those solr document will return as result, sorted by title ascending order. It will look like this

`Apple
 Banana
 Lemon
 Mango`

Now, what I want is to add another sorting which a bit tricky at least for me to implement :(. I want to sort it by title ascending and by popularity descending order which only involves the popularity that has a value of 3 and 2. The result should be like this

`Mango
 Banana
 Apple
 Lemon`

The question is what would be the query?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Order by an expression in Solr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6437512/order-by-an-expression-in-solr)

Answer (score 1):

You can sort it as follows:

```
sort=map(popularity,2,3, popularity,0) desc, title asc
```

Comment: many thanks I believe that's the right approach. I forgot to mention that I'm using php solarium and still figuring out how to incorporate solr functions in sort.